# Is there a way to change EE Control Panel menu/submenu to open on click instead of hover?

Tags: ee2, control-panel, javascript, css

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable EE control panel menu/submenu appear by hover. Instead I would like to set it up to open on click.

(i know that base menu initiate on click - first time, and then all other appear on hover), i would like to disable hover totaly.

Why this, well, i'm building nice custom EE control panel theme, with left vertical menu, but i'm having problems with submenu appearing when i don't want them to...

[image]

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... No

Perhaps too short, let me expand... Not easily

Ok, jokes aside, the JS which you wish to taget is dee pin the file `/themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/plugins/ee_navigation.js`. Note it is compressed, not sure you can even get the uncompressed version anywhere. You could try wading through it (good luck to you!) or perhaps try re-writing it.

You might get some milage from the [P&T CP CSS & JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) plugin, you could use this to 'reset' the menu and apply your own suckerfish style navigation...

Answer (score 0):

[Superfish EE Control Panel](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/superfish-ee-control-panel)

Might need tweaking to change events to click instead of hoverIntent and possibly this is only the top level menus not the sub-menu blow-outs.

Or at the very least you'll know how to inject your own JS into the CPanel interface and write your own for your needs.